# Script inside template wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I’ve made some tries to insert the script found to this link inside a wordpress template:

https://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery

I made the change necessary to reach my images directory:

$images_dir = ‘images/galleria’;
$thumbs_dir = ‘images/galleria/thumbs’;

The script doesn’t throw errors. WordPress create the page but it show only:

“There are no images in this gallery”

I try to set to 777 the permission on those folders, but nothing shows just the same.

What can I try please?

Answer (score 0):

It seams you wrongly set the directories `$images_dir` and `$thumbs_dir`.

If these directories are located in the wp-content/uploads folder (for example), you should do it as follows:

`$images_dir = trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR) . 'uploads/images/galleria'`

`$thumbs_dir = trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR) . 'uploads/images/galleria/thumbs'`

Comment: Hi!

Thank for you reply.

I've try the changes that you'd adviced me.

It seem that PHP script now works, because it show the "alt" attribute of the <img>.

If I control the img element through firebug the path of the "src" attribute
is /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/uploads/images/galleria.

Other images on the same page has the "src" attribute start from:

http://mysite/wp-content/

Comment: The constant `WP_CONTENT_DIR` holds the true server path to your wordpress wp-content folder. To get the URL of your wordpress site you need to use `WP_HOME` constant.

Comment: Hi!

If I make this change:

$images_dir = trailingslashit(WP_HOME) . 'uploads/images/galleria';
$thumbs_dir = trailingslashit(WP_HOME) . 'uploads/images/galleria/thumbs';

The script match the "else" statement and print a message of "There are no images in this gallery"

Comment: You need to add two new variables:
`$images_url = trailingslashit(WP_HOME) . 'uploads/images/galleria';`

`$thumbs_url = trailingslashit(WP_HOME) . 'uploads/images/galleria/thumbs';`

And than you need to change the line in your code that prints the link and thumb:

`echo '<a href="' . $images_url . $file . '" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="' . $thumbs_url . $file . '" /></a>';`

Comment: It can't reach the directory, I got the same message